# DAX: Running count distinct within selection

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I have a data table in my Power Query model looking like this:

| date | customer_id | category1 | category2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 |

I have a calculated meassure that counts distinct customer_id:

```
Distinct_cust:=DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[customer_id]))
```

This meassure works great in pivot table - it calculates corectly for all intersentions of any and all fields I add to the pivot and all subtotals.

Now I want to have a meassure that will work within the scope of given intersection but takes into account previous date values - it should return running count distinct of custeomer_id, but only for values of days that are incurrent pivot table.

Right now I have something like this that ALMOST works correctly:

```
Cumulative_Distinct_cust:=CALCULATE (
    [Distinct_cust];
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table1'[date] );
        'Table1'[date] <= MAX ('Table1'[date]) 
    )
)
```

This returns corectly running count distinct but only if all dates are not filtered out in my pivot table. As soon as I remove day nr 1 from pivot it still show running count distinct for day 2 and 3 af if day 1 was also taken into account:

[image: Example of problem im getting]

Brute force solution I came up with and I'm looking to replace is to add manually day filter inside FILTER statement which will limit date to only day 2 and 3:

```
Cumulative_Distinct_cust:=CALCULATE (
    [Distinct_cust];
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table1'[date] );
        AND(
              'Table1'[date] >= 2; <-- added this to filter
              'Table1'[date] <= MAX ( 'Table1'[date]) 
    )
))
```

[image: fixed version]

(You can see difference in column labeled as 1)

but obviously this is ugly and cumbersome to change every time I want to change date ranges. Is there any way to pass current available values of date field for purpose of this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
Cumulative_Distinct_cust:=VAR _date = MAX(Table1[date])
VAR _dates = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[date]); ALLSELECTED())
VAR _rt_dates = FILTER(_dates; Table1[date]<= _date)
RETURN
CALCULATE([Distinct_cust];_rt_dates)
```

Comment: It does not work. It gives exactly the same result as my first attempt. I'm looking ofr a way to find lower bound, as upper bound works just fine. Now I've tried to expand Your idea and added second variable that stored minimum of that column and in filtering used `>= MIN` AND `<= MAX`, but it turned it into essentially normal count distinct. What `MAX(Table1[date])` stores for each intersection is just a value of date for given intersection and same goes for `MIN()`, as the only date available in that intersection for calculation is that value alone, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Tetlanesh can you check now? I adjusted the code

Comment: I'l look later, just woke up :)

Comment: Thats it :) thank You :) So I assume `CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[date]); ALLSELECTED())` returns list of all dates without filtering applied by context of any single intersection of pivot table? And if yes, than I assume that `ALLSELECTED()` is responsible for that?

Comment: ALLSELECTED will modify any existing filter context, not only intersection - see more here https://dax.guide/allselected/